# Move events SVG by viewBox values

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I can't manage to save image position for next changing. It seems svg resets position every click, how do i save position? This things are confusing for me, and not much info in internet about it except this one
[draggable image](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/), but this tutorial is for 'x' and 'y' of inner object and not for viewBox values.

```js
 let image = document.querySelector("#parImage");
     let svg = image.querySelector("svg");
     let vbVals = svg.getAttribute("viewBox").split(" ");
     let CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();

     let x = 0;
     let y = 0;
     let z = 0;
     let w = 0;

     window.onload = function()
     {
      image.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
         image.addEventListener('mouseup', endDrag);
         image.addEventListener('mouseleave', endDrag);
     }

     function drag()
     {
      event.preventDefault();

      //x += 0.1;

   let X = (-((event.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a)) + 40;
   let Y = (-((event.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d)) + 30;

   svg.setAttribute("viewBox", 
    (X - x)  + " " + 
    (Y - y)  + " " + 
    vbVals[2]  + " " + 
    vbVals[3]);
     }


     function startDrag()
     {
      image.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);

      x = (-((event.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a)) + 40;
      y = (-((event.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d)) + 30;
      x -= parseFloat(vbVals[0]);
      y -= parseFloat(vbVals[1]);

      z = parseFloat(vbVals[2]);
      w = parseFloat(vbVals[3]);
     }

     function endDrag()
     {
      image.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag);
     }
```

```css
figure {
        width: 300px;
        background: wheat;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .static {
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }

    .draggable {
        cursor: move;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="section-library-detailbox">
        <div class="inner">
            <figure id="parImage"><svg class="draggable" viewBox="-15 -10 400 440">
                      <path d="M30,1h40l29,29v40l-29,29h-40l-29-29v-40z" stroke="#000" fill="none"/> 
  <path d="M31,3h38l28,28v38l-28,28h-38l-28-28v-38z" fill="#a23"/> 
  <text x="50" y="68" font-size="48" fill="#FFF" text-anchor="middle"><![CDATA[410]]></text>
                </svg></figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read `vbVals` on each drag and not only initially. As @Robert Longson said in the comment you can rely on the existing API to manipulate the viewbox;

```js
let image = document.querySelector("#parImage");
let svg = image.querySelector("svg");
//let vbVals = svg.getAttribute("viewBox").split(" ");

let CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();

let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let z = 0;
let w = 0;

window.onload = function() {
  image.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
  image.addEventListener('mouseup', endDrag);
  image.addEventListener('mouseleave', endDrag);
}

function drag() {
  event.preventDefault();

  //x += 0.1;

  let X = (-((event.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a)) + 40;
  let Y = (-((event.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d)) + 30;

  svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = (X - x);
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.y = (Y - y);
  /*svg.setAttribute("viewBox",
    (X - x) + " " +
    (Y - y) + " " +
    vbVals[2] + " " +
    vbVals[3]);*/
}


function startDrag() {
  image.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);

  x = (-((event.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a)) + 40;
  y = (-((event.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d)) + 30;

  //vbVals = svg.getAttribute("viewBox").split(" "); /* added this */
  x -= /*parseFloat(vbVals[0])*/ svg.viewBox.baseVal.x;
  y -= /*parseFloat(vbVals[1])*/ svg.viewBox.baseVal.y;

  z = /*parseFloat(vbVals[2])*/ svg.viewBox.baseVal.width;
  w = /*parseFloat(vbVals[3])*/ svg.viewBox.baseVal.height;
}

function endDrag() {
  image.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag);
}
```

```css
figure {
  width: 300px;
  background: wheat;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.static {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.draggable {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-library-detailbox">
  <div class="inner">
    <figure id="parImage"><svg class="draggable" viewBox="-15 -10 400 440">
                      <path d="M30,1h40l29,29v40l-29,29h-40l-29-29v-40z" stroke="#000" fill="none"/> 
  <path d="M31,3h38l28,28v38l-28,28h-38l-28-28v-38z" fill="#a23"/> 
  <text x="50" y="68" font-size="48" fill="#FFF" text-anchor="middle"><![CDATA[410]]></text>
                </svg></figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: viewBox has a DOM API so that split/recombine dance is not necessary. You can get/set individual values via svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = whatever or let x = svg.viewBox.baseVal.x

Comment: @RobertLongson is [this](http://html5index.org/SVG%20-%20SVGFitToViewBox.html) the definition? Strangely `SVGFitToViewBox` not present on MDN.